# Connect Asus Zenfone 5 to Linux box

Tags: debian, usb-drive, asus

I have `Asus Zenfone 5` phone and now I want to connect the device to my Debian 7 via `USB` to mount inner phone storage as external disk. So after it was connected I see in logs:

**dmesg**

```
[79836.644019] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[79836.779399] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b05, idProduct=5481
[79836.779403] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[79836.779406] usb 2-1: Product: Android
[79836.779408] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Android
[79836.779410] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0b05:5481 ASUSTek Computer, Inc
```

But no disk was mounted. `fdisk -l` does not show my phone.

After searching over the Internet I've found that Zenfone have some problem when connected via `usb2` and works fine with `usb3`. In Windows it forks fine with both `usb2` and `usb3`. But I miss `usb3` in my computer.

So my question - how can I connect `Asus Zenfone 5` to Debian via `usb2` or may be how can I emulate `usb3` with `usb2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Edit the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` and insert these 2 lines

```
#### #Asus Zenfone 5 (MTP+ADB)
ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", ATTR{idProduct}=="5481", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Before the line:

```
"# Autoprobe vendor-specific, communication and PTP devices"
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, @Stevenes Donato! Have I do something else, exclude adding the lines? To restart some service etc? I've edited the file but nothing changed after I connected the phone.

Comment: Ok, after adding lines suggested by @Stevened Donato I've installed kio-mtp and so suddenly it recognizes by KDE now

Answer (score 2):

I got using jmtpfs (it's in repository of wheezy). Enable MTP on zenfone usb options and do this how admin:

```
# mkdir asus
# jmtpfs asus -o allow_other
```

To umount:

```
# umount asus
```

Sorry, my eglish is very poor.

Comment: Still can't get it work. I've installed mtpfs and mtp-tools. mtp-detect says: `"Found 1 device(s): 0b05:5481 @ bus 2, dev 4"`. Ok so I run `sudo mtpfs /media/phone  -o allow_other`. It says: `Attempting to connect device. Android device detected, assigning default bug flags. Listing File Information on Device with name: (NULL)`. But nothing works. I can access /media/phone. Dolphin just hangs up.